# Counting white pixels between 2 points in an image

Tags: python, image-processing

I found starting and ending points of this thick white line and these are `[234, 2]`  and  `[134, 397]`. Now I want to calculate number of white pixels that are lying between these 2 points on a straight way. My purpose is to calculate the number of white pixels not on the thick line. I want to count white pixels that are lying on the line of width of 1 pixel. I'm very new to Python. I spent whole day in finding my solution but failed to find any way. How can I find that?

[image]

My effort to find the approximate starting and ending points is:

```
for y in range(height):
    for x in range(width):
         ....
          ....
    print(p1," , ",p2)
```

Now I'm facing trouble in next step. i.e. counting the number of white pixels between these 2 points.

Comment: You need to decide which [line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_drawing_algorithm) you want to rasterize the line between two points.  Once you determine that, this should be fairly simple.

Comment: Since you say you are new to python, I recommend you look into the [Python Imaging Library (PIL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_Imaging_Library) to help with the image processing.

Comment: @BenJones I beg your pardon, I edited my question, please give me solution to "comment" that I posted on your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the Bresenham line drawing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm), there are exactly

```
max(abs(p1.x - p2.x), abs(p1.y - p2.y)) - 1
```

pixels in between points `p1` and `p2` (not counting the pixels `p1` or `p2`).

This line is a 1-pixel thick line.

Note that the number of pixels does not correspond to the Euclidean distance between the points, but to the L-infinity distance, also called max-norm, chessboard distance or [Chebyshev distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_distance).

---

**Edit:** The updated question is totally different. The above will be the upper bound.

To count the actual number of white pixels on the line between the two points, you need to draw that line. The Wikipedia link above gives details on **the** algorithm to draw lines. [Here is a very simple implementation in MATLAB](https://www.crisluengo.net/index.php/archives/400), should be easy to translate to Python. Though instead of actually drawing the line, you would read the pixel values, and count the ones that are white.

@Ben Jones suggested a Python implementation of Bresenham's algorithm. It needn't be that complicated. Here is a simple Python script that finds all pixels on the straight line between the two points (translated from the MATLAB version linked above):

```
p1 = np.array([0,0])
p2 = np.array([7,4]) % Two example points.

p = p1
d = p2-p1
N = np.max(np.abs(d))
s = d/N
print(np.rint(p).astype('int'))
for ii in range(0,N):
   p = p+s;
   print(np.rint(p).astype('int'))
```

This produces the output:

```
[0 0]
[1 1]
[2 1]
[3 2]
[4 2]
[5 3]
[6 3]
[7 4]
```

Now all that's left is reading the pixel values at these coordinates, and determining whether they're white or not.

Comment: I was trying same thing that you suggested. But apologies, I didn't mention early that given line is thick dotted white line. I want solution to this problem. Apologies for not mentioning this early. Can you suggest me solution for this image? Thank you very much!

Comment: @KnowledgeSeeker: that's a whole different question... I've edited my answer to give an outline of how to do this. Please try to implement it, if you run into difficulties consider posting a new question with your code.

Comment: FWIW, here's a Python implementation (found with the google search "Bresenham algorithm python") https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Bitmap/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm#Python

Comment: @Ben: Thanks for the link. I think drawing a line is a lot simpler if one forgets about trying to use only integers. See the update to the answer.

Comment: Oh yeah that makes sense - that floating point algorithm is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a line algorithm like [Bresenham's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm), and both points are on the thick white line as you have described, then the number of white pixels between the two points will actually be something like:

```
num_white_pixels = max(abs(pt0[0] - pt1[0]), abs(pt0[1] - pt1[1]))
```

Because, presumably the entire line will fall in the white region, and the number of pixels that make up a line of width 1 is just `max( dx, dy )`, give or take one pixel, depending on whether you want to include the end points.

Comment: Ben Jones, I was trying same thing that you suggested. But apologies, I didn't mention early that given line is thick dotted white line. I want solution to this problem. Apologies for not mentioning this early. Can you suggest me solution for this image? Thank you very much!

Comment: That is a very different problem statement! And the solution is a bit more involved.  I suggest you load a pixel array using the PIL, as I suggested in the comments.  Then implement Bresenham's algorithm, except **counting** white pixels instead of **drawing** them.